# 1画面に複数個のUICollectionViewを配置した場合のデリゲート設定

Tags: ios, swift

StoryBoardで、1画面に複数のUICollectionViewを配置しました。
UICollectionViewのdataSourceとdelegateはStoryBoard上で
OutletをViewControllerと紐付けてあります。

コードでは下記のようにUICollectionViewDelegate等を指定しています。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
}
```

複数個のUICollectionViewがある場合、どちらのUICollectionViewのイベントであるかを
指定できるのでしょうか？

また、UICollectionViewをカスタムクラスファイル(CustomCollectionView1.swift)というようなファイルを作って、それぞれで、デリゲート等を指定するのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

予めStoryBoard上もしくはviewDidLoad内等で個々のUICollectionViewのtagに識別用のタグを設定しておき、

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

等のデリゲートメソッドの引数のcollectionViewのtagの値を取り出すことによりどのUICollectionViewのイベントかを識別することができます。

Comment: tagによって識別することができました。ありがとうございます。
1つのUIViewController.swiftの中に、画面にあるすべてのコントロールの処理を記述すると煩雑になりそうなのですが、例えば、UICollectionViewに関わる処理だけ別の.swiftファイルに記述するなど、外だしにすることはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、できます。デリゲートメソッドの引数やその他の処理に必要なデータを引数として別クラスに渡してメソッドを呼び出すことで、見やすいコードになるかと思います。解説サイトや書籍等では、説明のしやすさや見やすさ？等の理由から1つのUIViewController.swiftの中で完結させている例が多いですが、実際の開発ではMVCの考え方に基いて処理内容は別クラスで実装するのが一般的だと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。UICollecti‌​onView.swiftの中で、デリゲートメソッド等を用意しておいて、ロジック部分については、別クラスで実装するようなイメージと捉えました。

Answer (score 0):

Storyboard上のUICollectionViewインスタンスをViewControllerのIBOutletなプロパティに保持しておいて、デリゲートメソッドでは引数のcollectionViewがプロパティと同じオブジェクトを指しているかを比較するというはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法でも試してみます。